Differential equation of all non-vertical lines in a plane
I have the following question:

Find the differential equation of family of non-vertical lines in a plane.

To solve the question, I do the following:
A non-vertical line would be: $y = mx + c$
and taking first differential coefficients of both sides: $y^\prime = m$
once more: $y^{\prime\prime} = 0$, which is the required answer.
However, I ask, where do we use the condition that the line must be non-vertical, I mean we never said or assumed that and even if we did, we never used the fact that $m$ must not be $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.
Similar would be if I ask the differential equation of all non-horizontal lines. Here $m$ (that is slope) must not be $0$, but we would never use that fact while finding the differential equation, if the above method is used.
Are the conditions that $m$ must not be equal to $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ or $m$ must not be equal to $0$ (we may call them the boundary conditions for respective questions above, if I am right?) being utilised automatically; if yes then how and if no then what more things should I do?
Any help is appreciated!

Well, $\tan \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ is undefined, so we don't need to worry.

As $y^{\prime\prime}=0\implies y=c_1x+c_2$., the general solution doesn't include vertical lines.

@SeanRoberson what about the second case when $m$ must not be zero, that is, for horizontal lines?

@MathGuy you mean $c_1$ must be a finite value and not $tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$? Because indefinite integration gives a finite constant?

@Moo yes I do, for the horizontal lines. Thanks!

The equation of a vertical line is $x=Cte$. The $y$ coordinate is not used, so you cannot have an $y=f(x)$ equation. Excluding the vertical lines in the question statement is just a goody so that you have not to explain why you had to exclude them....

@SergeBallesta That I think is a great explanation. Thanks!

Since the set of real numbers is $(-\infty,\infty)$, the arbitrary constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ can only assume finite values. So, the case of vertical lines is automatically excluded as the constants cannot take undefined values.

Since $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is not defined, if we write $y=mx+c$, then this can represent every non-vertical line in the $xy$-plane as $m$ being a real number can assume only finite values, i.e, in $(-\infty,\infty)$. Hence, you don’t have to worry about excluding vertical lines. The differential equation in this case becomes $y’’(x)=0$ as you have mentioned.
For non-horizontal lines, we can say that the value of $\frac1{m}$ must be finite as $m\ne0$. Since $x’(y)=\frac1{m}$, the differential equation in this case is analogously $x’’(y)=0$.
Similarly, the condition or differential inequality for the family of lines with slope being any value except a particular value, say $a$, is represented by $y’(x)\ne a$.

+1, I agree!...

Happy to help :D
